# List of frequently used apps in Android

Tags: android

How can  I make a list of frequently used apps at the top with a divider just like YouTube app?

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
```

It returns all the available apps to the shareIntent.

I can sort the apps alphabetically using the below code

```
Collections.sort(list, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
```

But how can I sort the list based upon the usage of the apps??

Comment: If Android tracks this information, AFAIK it does not make it available via the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanx for your comment... it looks like only option left to me is to manually sort the apps based upon package names(i.e facebook,Whats app,G+ etc)

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to get permissions like the tvusage and digital wellbeing apps do. Here is a review of tvusage: https://www.xda-developers.com/tvusage-brings-digital-wellbeing-and-app-lock-to-android-tv/amp/

This requires accessibility permissions display over other apps, and you specifically have to allow the application access by manually granting access to "make this app searchable" and on Android 10 Device Admin Apps, and one other I will come back and update this to reflect, Android 10 has Device Admin Apps, everything before that looks like it requires three very specific permissions that need to be manually set and android does not give apps ability to request, you have to go into the setting and manually turn them on.

I will come back to this and update what the exact names are of these and add the last one. I am needing any open source that goes into the TVUsage app and the Digital Wellbeing App to review further but my intent is to keep a very clear and observable log of my activities on logs sent to my server when network available than I can do stuff in elastic and such.

In future if your app uses this, it is logical you will need to set that app as your assistant, as Google assistant currently handles a lot here and for its scope and usage may be a limitation to the engine your app activities go to. You can see your app activity on https://myactivity.google.com and you can grant access to some of that via a cloud app key and may be workaroundish but should be able to grab from the digital Wellbeing application already all cleaned up pretty and usable directly on the device, not sure how app signatures are working these days but suspect apps install with like a GID, and can potentially can be keyed to the package manager that installed them and file structures non transferable to other device,  latter of all I said here is yet to really present itself, but is on way. An app instance that is both immutable and unique is possible.

The link below is a step forward for in app display of frequently used apps on Android, could be easier than presented here as this looks to basically rebuild Digital Wellbeing.
https://blog.usejournal.com/building-an-app-usage-tracker-in-android-fe79e959ab26